# Wrong execution path of cc in xcodebuild

Tags: xcode, xcode4, xcodebuild

I downloaded and installed Xcode 4.2 on Lion. With installed examples, I could build them with Xcode IDE, but I got those error messages when I tried to execute the same project file with `xcodebuild`.

```
can't exec '/Developer/Library/Xcode/PrivatePlugIns/Xcode3Core.ideplugin/Contents/SharedSupport/
Developer/Library/Xcode/Plug-ins/LLVM GCC 4.2.xcplugin/Contents/Resources/
cc -arch i386' (No such file or directory)
```

The problem is that it tries to call `"...\cc -arch i386"` as a command, but the cc is not in that directory.

What's wrong with this `xcodebuild` setup? Why xcodebuild tries to call the cc based on the wrong directory information?

Comment: I have this issue as well.. anyone?

Answer (score 1):

During `xcodebuild`, I need to specify the path of `CC`, otherwise wrong one got used.

```
make CC="$PLATFORM_DEVELOPER_BIN_DIR/cc"
```